# Mysql total price, sum, and distinct(product)

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql table:

```
product_id   selling_price
10            200
10            200
11            100
11            100
13            300
```

How can I return something like below

```
product_id    total    total_selling_price
10            2        400
11            2        200
13            1        300
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  product_ID,
        COUNT(*) totalCount,
        SUM(selling_price) total_selling_price
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY product_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92464/1)
- [List of GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ PRODUCT_ID ║ TOTALCOUNT ║ TOTAL_SELLING_PRICE ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║         10 ║          2 ║                 400 ║
║         11 ║          2 ║                 200 ║
║         13 ║          1 ║                 300 ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: +1 correct snd nice fiddle and formatting, but why do you left justify the *second* word of each (major) line?

Answer (score 2):

You need `group by aggregate function with count and sum`.

Try this.

```
select   product_id, count(product_id), sum(selling_price)
from     tablename
group by product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving it a shot, not tested locally

```
SELECT  product_id,
        COUNT(product_id),
        SUM(Amount)
FROM    yourTable
GROUP BY    product_id
```